# How can I delete this space on my flutter app

Tags: flutter

I need some light support. As you can see in the image, between my AppBar and the cards there is a space that I have not been able to eliminate. I have tried to remove this space from my flutter app but I can't seem to find where I can remove this space. Can someone help me to find a way to eliminate this space?

[image]

My entire code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/config/constant.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/commodities.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/response_options.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/token.dart';
import 'package:my_app/src/pages/page_seleted_index.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:my_app/widgets/shipper_drawer.dart';

class CreateShipmentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Token token;
  const CreateShipmentPage({required this.token, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CreateShipmentPage> createState() => _CreateShipmentPageState();
}

class _CreateShipmentPageState extends State<CreateShipmentPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          _CustomAppBar(token: widget.token),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getData(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<OptionsResponse?> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else {
                  return DisplayOptions(
                      snapshot.data!.options.commodities, widget.token);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: ShipperDrawer(token: widget.token),
    );
  }
}

class _CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Token token;
  const _CustomAppBar({required this.token, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverAppBar(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(3, 9, 23, 1),
      
      pinned: true,
      title: Text(
        "Hi, ${token.user.name} \nWhat do you want ship?",
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),

      centerTitle: false,
      flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
        
        
        background: FadeInImage(
          placeholder: AssetImage('assets/loading.gif'),
          image: AssetImage('assets/truck.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Peter Koltai.
You need `wrap` your `SliverFillRemaining` widget with

```
MediaQuery.removePadding({removeTop: true, child: ...})
```

There also default spacing in silver widget.

Or you can use `SliverList` widget just like this

```
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Card(
        child: Container(height: 44.0,child: Center(child: Text("$index"))),
      );
    },
    childCount: 5
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter adds automatic padding above some widgets, for example from `ListView` documentation:

> By default, ListView will automatically pad the list's scrollable extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's padding.

Wrap your cards widget like this to remove top padding:

```
MediaQuery.removePadding({removeTop: true, child: ...})
```