# Flutter) How can I remove this space(padding) in this screen?

Tags: flutter

[image]

This is result of SearchScreen. I think that I never give padding or magin between "Search TextField" widget and "Masonry GridView" Widget. When I execute this snippet of code on iOS simulator. As picture can see, there's a little white space between.

```
class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // Search TextField
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                        onPressed: () {
                          /* Clear the search field */
                        },
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Search...',
                      border: InputBorder.none),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // MasonryGridView
          SizedBox(
            height: 740,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 3.0,
              ),
              child: MasonryGridView.builder(
                itemCount: 8,
                gridDelegate:
                    const SliverSimpleGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/${(index + 1).toString()}.jpg",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just want to know reason that Why there is a space in there and How can I remove that?

Comment: fyi, you have unnecessary use of widgets that makes no sense or at least can be optimised !

Comment: It is possible your images aren't fitting on grid

Comment: Instead of using fixed height in` SizedBox` use your screen height .
Instead of ` height: 740,`  use ` height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69893629/17642856

Flutter adds automatic padding above some widgets, for example from ListView documentation:

> By default, ListView will automatically pad the >list's scrollable extremities to avoid partial >obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's padding.

Wrap your cards widget like this to remove top padding:

```
MediaQuery.removePadding({context: context,removeTop: true, child: ...})
```